# Laravel query delays and 'session' queries despite database 'file' driver used

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm currently using Laravel for a project I'm working on, and my web server has recently started performing very slowly upon page load, whereby each page can take up to eight seconds until loaded.

Thus far, I've determined that the slowness is not caused by the following:

- DNS issue; issue occurs when I navigate directly to the server's IP
- Apache issue; a blank PHP file with 'PHPinfo()' loads instantly without any delay
- Load; Server's CPU usage is never above 20%

Following the above steps, the issues only occur in the live environment, where my development environment shows no signs of delay.

After analyzing some cache grind logs, I found that the `PDOStatement->execute` call appears to take up the largest amount of delay.

I then enabled `long_query_time` logging in MySQL to further determine the issue. My findings show that most of my queries are being executed quickly, well under one second; however, I've found that any `site_session` queries executed are taking up to six seconds to be executed.

As a further troubleshooting step, I attempted to temporarily change my `sessions` drive to `file` instead of `database`; however, I'm finding that the following queries are still being executed after each page load:

```
# Time: 150813 23:37:12
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost [127.0.0.1]
# Query_time: 3.035622  Lock_time: 0.000022 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
SET timestamp=1439509032;
update `site_sessions` set `payload` = 'YTo1OntzOjY6Il90b2tlbiI7czo0MDoibHk0YVo2MG16c09acTBTSnVnYUlJVTFNM0VrU3B2ekdiRFJyYmRzWiI7czo5OiJfcHJldmlvdXMiO2E6MTp7czozOiJ1cmwiO3M6MjY6Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cuY29ycGxlYWd1ZXMuY29tIjt9czo1OiJmbGFzaCI7YToyOntzOjM6Im9sZCI7YTowOnt9czozOiJuZXciO2E6MDp7fX1zOjM4OiJsb2dpbl84MmU1ZDJjNTZiZGQwODExMzE4ZjBjZjA3OGI3OGJmYyI7czoxOiIxIjtzOjk6Il9zZjJfbWV0YSI7YTozOntzOjE6InUiO2k6MTQzOTUwOTAyODtzOjE6ImMiO2k6MTQzOTQ5Nzc5MjtzOjE6ImwiO3M6MToiMCI7fX0=', `last_activity` = '1439509029' where `id` = 'ba62f70745c5455611c3fe3bf008fa213c22a7f9';
# Time: 150813 23:37:27
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost [127.0.0.1]
# Query_time: 1.071487  Lock_time: 0.000026 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
SET timestamp=1439509047;
update `site_sessions` set `payload` = 'YTo1OntzOjY6Il90b2tlbiI7czo0MDoiOGhiVVVobTFjTERrU1ZXR25weTdMWHlQRlMzTmtkOWhIZzFSdHQ1QSI7czo5OiJfcHJldmlvdXMiO2E6MTp7czozOiJ1cmwiO3M6MjY6Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cuY29ycGxlYWd1ZXMuY29tIjt9czo1OiJmbGFzaCI7YToyOntzOjM6Im9sZCI7YTowOnt9czozOiJuZXciO2E6MDp7fX1zOjM4OiJsb2dpbl84MmU1ZDJjNTZiZGQwODExMzE4ZjBjZjA3OGI3OGJmYyI7czoxOiIxIjtzOjk6Il9zZjJfbWV0YSI7YTozOntzOjE6InUiO2k6MTQzOTUwOTA0NjtzOjE6ImMiO2k6MTQzOTUwNDQzODtzOjE6ImwiO3M6MToiMCI7fX0=', `last_activity` = '1439509046' where `id` = 'c3e95cf7c317ad340aa28c61bf323e008eaa5ff0';
```

Can anyone shed some light on this issue, or equally, provide additional troubleshooting steps that will help me determine the root cause?

Any feedback is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

Here's the `TABLE STATUS` information:

```
+--------------------------------------------------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-----------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| Name                                             | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time | Check_time | Collation       | Checksum | Create_options | Comment |
+--------------------------------------------------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-----------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| site_sessions                                    | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |   18 |            910 |       16384 |               0 |        16384 |  10485760 |           NULL | 2015-07-20 03:40:32 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci |     NULL |                |         |
+--------------------------------------------------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-----------------+----------+----------------+---------+
```

My `session.php` file:

```
<?php
return [
    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER'),
    'lifetime' => 320,
    'expire_on_close' => true,
    'encrypt' => false,
    'files' => storage_path().'/framework/sessions',
    'connection' => null,
    'table' => 'sessions',
    'lottery' => [2, 100],
    'cookie' => 'clgs_session',
    'path' => '/',
    'domain' => null,
    'secure' => false,
];
```

(Note: I've specified the `SESSION_DRIVER` variable as `file` in `.env` and I've also attempted to set it manually in `session.php`)

Finally, here's my `site_sessions` table structure:

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE site_sessions;

 CREATE TABLE `site_sessions` (
   `id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
   `payload` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
   `last_activity` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `user_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
   UNIQUE KEY `sessions_id_unique` (`id`),
   KEY `sessions_user_id_index` (`user_id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Just to note, the `user_id` field is to help me determine which users are associated with each session, in order to obtain a list of users that are currently online. I've never had an issue with the aspect.

Are there any additional troubleshooting steps I can perform in order to determine the slow queries?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have an index on your `id` column in the sessions table? Also, can we see your `session.php` config file?

Comment: @Scopey I've added all the information requested. Thanks